# What happens after an Aboleth's body is remade in the Elemental Plane of Water following its death?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, planes

According to the *Monster Manual* (p. 14), when an [Aboleth](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/mm/monsters-a#Aboleth) dies, its spirit goes back to the Elemental Plane of Water to get a new body:

> If an aboleth's body is destroyed, its spirit returns to the Elemental Plane of Water, where a new body coalesces for it over days or months.

What happens next? How does the Aboleth return to the Material Plane? Can it choose where to go?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### The aboleth is now stuck in the Plane of Water until they find a way back.

Nothing in the aboleth monster description says that they automatically return to the Material Plane when their body is reconstituted. Their statblock has no planar teleportation ability either, so unless the DM asserts otherwise, the aboleth has to find their own way back if they wish.

An aboleth can still use normal methods to travel back to the Material Plane. They can find a planar portal, acquire a minion spellcaster who can cast *plane shift* for them, and so on. How this travel works depends entirely on the portal or spell used. It might take years or decades to find a portal, or the genius aboleth may have even prepared one ahead of time. This leaves a lot up to the DM.

The ability of the aboleth to reconstitute is new to D&D 5th edition, so we cannot consult earlier editions' sources for how this ability works. The 5e sources do not give much in the way of additional clarity here.

We know from its *Monster Manual* entry that some aboleths actually live in the Plane of Water, meaning that a reconstituted aboleth has the option to stay:

> Aboleths dwell in watery environments, including ocean abysses, deep lakes, and the Elemental Plane of Water.

*Tales from the Yawning Portal*, p.134, has an aboleth who is trapped in a pool, implying that they cannot simply *teleport* or *plane shift* to escape.

Answer (score 10):

#### Once it has a new body, it does whatever it wants (as long as it's capable of doing it).

It's dramatic because of the death -> recorporation, but this is a pretty straightforward case similar to teleportation.

The aboleth dies, on whatever plane, and as long as it is not somehow restricted from doing so its spirit goes to the Elemental Plane of Water where it gets a new body. At that point it's alive again (or "again", depending on how you want to think of it). It can hang out in the Elemental Plane of Water, it can find a way to travel to another plane (there are many methods), or do anything else it could ever have done.